# git hooks: Detect which system is running

Tags: git, hook

I wanted to detect in a git hook which system is running over git:
git GUI
git Bash
...

Is there a way to know this information inside the hook?

Well at least, I wanted to know if I'm using git GUI or not.

The reason behind this is:
In order to git GUI to show message to the users it requires the commit to fail (exit number != 0).
If I send the exit number != 0 to a git bash user, he loses the commit message.

Comment: Which git hook are you using?

Comment: pre-commit, prepare-commit-msg, commit-msg